# Find and return multiple independent strings

Tags: r, string-matching, grepl

I have a table with several different strings in the same column. I would like to be able to search that column and find different strings and then return different results for each different string. For example, if I have the following column of data:

```
Seq_ID   Column2
    1. RNA-ATI_1    
    2. RNA-ATI_2
    3.  DNA-FU_1
    4.  FU-DNA_2
    5. DNA-TP1_1
    6. RNA-TP1_2
    7.  RNA-BL_1
    8.  BL-RNA_2
```

I would like to search for the string "ATI" and return "ATI" and search "FU" and return "FU" and "TP1" and return "TP1" so that I can build a new table with the strings in a separate `column2`.
I can use `grepl` to do this for a single value, but I can't figure out how to do it for multiple outputs. Some of the caveats are that the data is not always in the same order or separated by 
the same symbol.

```
y <- ifelse(grepl("*ATI", tab$Sequence_ID), "Analytical treatment interruption", " ")
```

This seems to work for just one, but I can't figure out how to expand it to work for several.

In the end I would like:

```
 Seq_ID      Column2
     1.    RNA-ATI_1    ATI
     2.    RNA-ATI_2    ATI
     3.     DNA-FU_1     FU
     4.     FU-DNA_2     FU
     5.    DNA-TP1_1    TP1
     6.    RNA-TP1_2    TP1
     7.     RNA-BL_1     BL 
     8.     BL-RNA_2     BL
```

Comment: So, your expected output absolutely doesn't match what you are trying to do? In your `grepl`, you try to replace `ATI` by `Analytical treatment interruption`. I don't see this in your output. How is it relevant here? Or is your expected output partial and only a XY problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `stringr::str_extract_all`

```
y <- stringr::string_extract_all(dat$Column2,"ATI|FU|TP1|BL")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could specify multiple patterns to a `regexpr` call, assuming they are all distinct strings. E.g.:

```
regmatches(dat$Column2, regexpr("ATI|FU|TP1|BL", dat$Column2))
#[1] "ATI" "ATI" "FU"  "FU"  "TP1" "TP1" "BL"  "BL"
```

This would have analogies in the `stringi` `stringr` etc packages too using their `str_extract` and `stri_extract` functions - see @mnel and his answer above.